# Using this keyword in a self-maintained Singleton class Or use instance always

Tags: java, android, singleton, this, locationmanager

I am implementing a singleton class which maintains itself, meaning it has a private constructor and a getInstance method

```
public class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {

  private static GPSTracker instance;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private field1, field2 ...;

  public static GPSTracker getInstance() {

        if(instance == null)
            instance = new GPSTracker();
        return instance;
    }

  ...
}
```

**Question 1**:

Since this GPSTracker class maintains its own singleton object (called instace), does each and every method I implement in this class which refers to class fields / members should be using members like: `this.field1`
or always `instance.field1` ?

**Question 2: (similar to 1)**

As you can see In my example above I need to **Override** abstract methods from LocationListener, Usually until now registering to GPS was like:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
```

Since I had my overrides implemented in the same class, do i need to use the `instance` singleton obejct here as well (instead of this)?

**I'll appreciate if you can elaborate why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer apply to both questions.

**Short answer:**

Technically it doesn't matter. using the **`this.field1`** or **`instance.field1`** (In a singleton case).

Although it will work correct and the same in both cases (using **`this`** or **`instance`** object) it is more recommended to use the **`this`** keyword.

**Detailed answer:**

Coming to think about this I realized that it doesn't matter, in this case the singleton object will be calling methods which will refer to class members.
Since the singleton object will be the caller - using **`this.field1`** will refer to the singleton's **`field1`**.

Even if a class was maintaining multiple objects (which are from the same type of the class) whenever an object will call its members the **`this`** will always work and refer to the caller's fields.
 That's the whole trick of the **`this`** keyword !

**Conclusion** - a better practice will be using **`this.field`**  instead of **`instance.field`**

[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709606/3263659) gave also a good point - use the **`this`** so if in the future you will make the class non singleton, your code will be ready for it and you won't need to change back all **`instance.field`** to **`this.field`** (seperation of concerns as he mentioned).

Answer (score 4):

Use `this`, so that if you later want it to not be a singleton, all that code won't have to change. The `getInstance()` method should be the only method that uses the static `instance` field.

It's called [**separation of concerns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

The `getInstance()` method is the only method that is concerned about the *singleton* aspect of the class.